# cvxpy returns problem unbounded status unexplicably

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve an integer version of the blending problem. I want to maximize a linear objective and I have several linear constraints. The code is:

```py
# we'll need both cvxpy and numpy
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 5  # the number of products
M = 5 # the number of materials

# material availability of each item
material_bounds = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=M)
# value of each product
v = cp.Constant(np.random.uniform(1, 15, size=N))
# material needed for each item
materials_needed = np.random.uniform(5, 10, size=(M,N))
# define the x vector this time it is integer
x = cp.Variable(N, integer=True)
# define the constraint
constraints = []

for i in range(M):
    constraints.append(
        cp.Constant(materials_needed[i]) @ x <= cp.Constant(material_bounds[i]))

# define the target function
target = v @ x

# define the problem
mix_problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(target), constraints)
print(mix_problem)
# solve the problem.
mix_problem.solve(verbose=True)


print("Solution:", x.value)
print("Total value:", v @ x.value)
print("Total weight:", materials_needed @ x.value)
```

When printing the problem it is formulated as expected. But the output of the solver is:

```
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.2.2                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Your problem has 5 variables, 5 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Compiling problem (target solver=GLPK_MI).
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Reduction chain: FlipObjective -> Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> GLPK_MI
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Applying reduction FlipObjective
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Applying reduction GLPK_MI
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Finished problem compilation (took 1.960e-02 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Invoking solver GLPK_MI  to obtain a solution.
*     0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (5)
*     1: obj =  -7.818018602e+01 inf =   0.000e+00 (4)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Problem status: unbounded
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Optimal value: inf
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Compilation took 1.960e-02 seconds
(CVXPY) Nov 22 08:51:07 AM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 3.681e-04 seconds
Solution: None
```

I do not understand why is the problem unbounded since I have <= constrains. Can anyone help me please?

**cvxpy version:** 1.2.2
**Python version:** 3.8

I have read the cvxpy documentation but it didn't help too much. I have tried to change the way I build the constrains. Initially it was `materials_needed @ x <= material_bounds` but all the examples I have seen so far have a list with several constratins instead of using matrix form.

Comment: Did you not intend to declare ``x`` as positive?

Comment: Above comment is correct.  Without the non-negative constraint on `x` the problem is unbounded.

Comment: I tried it but it seems that you can't declare a variable both as an integer and positive at the same time. I got the following error ```ValueError: Cannot set more than one special attribute in Variable.``` Also, I don't think the problem is unbounded because of the sign since I am maximizing and my coefficients are all positive, the solution should be all positive. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Michal Adamaszek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9332433/michal-adamaszek) and [AirSquid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10789207/airsquid) comments I figured a solution out.

I don't understand yet why is this necessary but I added the restriction `x >= 0` to explicitly force the solution to be non-negative. This is the code:

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

N = 5  # the number of products
M = 5 # the number of materials

# material availability of each item
material_bounds = np.random.uniform(50, 80, size=M)
# value of each product
v = cp.Constant(np.random.uniform(1, 15, size=N))
# material needed for each item
materials_needed = np.random.uniform(5, 10, size=(M,N))
# define the x vector this time it is integer
x = cp.Variable(N, integer=True)
# define the constraint
constraints = [
    materials_needed @ x <= material_bounds,
    x >= 0 # additional non-negativity constraint
]

# define the target function
target = v @ x

# define the problem
mix_problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(target), constraints)
# solve the problem.
mix_problem.solve()


print("Solution:", x.value)
print("Total value:", v.value @ x.value)
print("Materials used:", materials_needed @ x.value)
```

I also modified the constraints to use the matrix form which is more elegant IMO.

I think the original question is solved but I would still like to know what is this constraint necessary since I am maximizing and the solution should be always non-negative.

Comment: Let's say you want to maximize ``x+2y`` subject to ``x+y<=10`` without any nonnegativity restrictions. Then you can take ``y`` as big as you like,  ``x=10-y``, and your objective is ``10+y``, so it is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally understood the issue.